# In SoapUI , .docx file creation of xml pretty print by groovy and Apache poi, how?

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I have wrote an groovy script in soapui for .docx file creation, its working fine and printing also . But the request XML and response XML are not coming in Pretty print , its coming as a paragraph.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
def groovy=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def project=context.testCase.testSuite.project

def testStepCount= testRunner.testCase.getTestStepCount();
log.info testStepCount
def request=project.getTestSuiteAt(0).getTestCaseAt(1).getTestStepAt(4).getProperty("Request").getValue().toString()

XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("c:\\Inputparagraph.docx"));

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\createparagraph00.docx"));

XWPFParagraph p2 = docx.createParagraph();
XWPFRun r2 = p2.createRun();
r2.setText(request);
docx.write(out);
out.close();
```

And the output looks like:

[image: screenshot of word with the actual and the wanted formatting]

Answer (score 0):

you can split your input and add multiple runs with line breaks.  see the `XXX` tagged part

```
@Grapes([@Grab('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11'),@Grab('org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1')])

import java.io.FileInputStream
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*

def sometext='''\
A
BC
D'''

XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument()
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/out.docx"))

XWPFParagraph p = docx.createParagraph()
// XXX
sometext.eachLine{ line ->
    p.createRun().with{
        setText(line)
        addBreak()
    }
}
docx.write(out)
out.close()
```

BTW: you don't need `;` to end lines in groovy

Comment: by this I am able to get the space but not getting pretty print for xml response. Xml are not structured as it should be.

Comment: and that means what? no indenting?  could you please provide the XML you are working with in the question and alos the current result.

Comment: I have already share the screen-shot for Output , please find the Input below:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hp="HP.SOAQ.SampleApp">   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>      <hp:GetFlights>         <!--Optional:-->
         <hp:DepartureCity>Denver</hp:DepartureCity>         <!--Optional:-->         <hp:ArrivalCity>London</hp:ArrivalCity>
      </hp:GetFlights>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: thanks a lot I am able to use the above code as u have mentioned correctly in my previous code and its works fine. Thanks a ton for your help, really appreciable. :)